# elementID.style.display='block' not work in chrome but working in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
function loadMyitem(output, counter, msg, FileQuery) {

    //alert(output)
    if( window.XMLHttpRequest )
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 1) {
            msg.style.display = 'block';
            msg.innerHTML = "";
        } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            msg.style.display = 'block';
            msg.innerHTML = "";

            var respStr = new Array();

            respStr = xmlhttp.responseText.split('|');
            optStr = output.split('|');
            var CC1 = $(counter).val();
            for (i = 0; i < respStr.length; i++) {
                //alert(respStr[i]); 
                document.getElementById(optStr[i] + CC1).value = respStr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    //document.getElementByID(msg).innerHTML=inputText;
    xmlhttp.open("get", FileQuery, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This works on Firefox, but when I execute this function in chrome or opera then its give error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

What is the problem in this function?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why on God's green earth are you using plain vanilla AJAX?

Comment: @j08691 He's not using jQuery here.

Comment: What is `msg`? Can you show where you call `loadMyItem`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `msg` is a string with an element ID, try this...

```
var msgElement = document.getElementById(msg);
if (msgElement) {
    msgElement.style.display = 'block';
    // and so on
}
```